# Rearranging an expression for floating point accuracy?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

Does Mathematica have the feature of rearranging an expression with the goal of minimizing floating point accuracy errors? I'm asking this because I have some long expressions that really suffer when calculated with single-precision floating point. I'm almost sure their accuracy can be improved for single-precision (even if it's just a bit), so I was wondering if Mathematica has some sort of `FullSimplifyForFPAccuracy[]`...

Otherwise, are you aware of any other tool capable of doing that?

Comment: [Herbie: automatically improving floating point accuracy](https://herbie.uwplse.org/)

Comment: Woa! What a tool... it even generates C source... Incredible, I didn't know of it. Thanks a  lot, @MarcoB